# CSV sort by column 3 and counter in front

Tags: awk, sed, sort

I would like from this table

```
"ResNR";"ResNAME";"CustomerNAME";"CustomerID";"Date";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"
"12431";"TEST";"Kunde 1";"10272";"20.06.2017 10:35";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"
"12431";"TEST";"Kunde 2";"10207";"13.11.2017 14:08";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"
"12431";"TEST";"Kunde 2";"10328";"09.05.2018 09:22";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"
"12431";"TEST";"Kunde 1";"10189";"16.05.2018 17:47";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"
"12431";"TEST";"Kunde 3";"10189";"18.06.2018 20:07";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"
"12431";"TEST";"Kunde 1";"10229";"13.11.2018 11:14";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"
"12431";"TEST";"Kunde 2";"10348";"28.01.2019 09:06";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"
"12431";"TEST";"Kunde 3";"10340";"06.02.2019 11:13";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"
"12431";"TEST";"Kunde 1";"10349";"22.02.2019 17:06";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"
"12431";"TEST";"Kunde 2";"10333";"27.02.2019 20:18";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"
```

This is how the output should be
Everything should be sorted by customer name.
The first 2 columns can be deleted.
Then the counter must go into the first column

```
Sold;CustomerNAME;CustomerID;Date;Column1;_1;_2;_3;_4;_5;_6;_7;_8;_9;_10;_11;_12;_13;_14;_15;_16;_17;_18;_19;_20;_21;_22;_23;_24;_25;_26;_27
s01;Kunde 1;10272;20.06.2017 10:35;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s01;Kunde 1;10189;16.05.2018 17:47;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
S01;Kunde 1;10229;13.11.2018 11:14;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s01;Kunde 1;10349;22.02.2019 17:06;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s02;Kunde 2;10207;13.11.2017 14:08;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s02;Kunde 2;10328;09.05.2018 09:22;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s02;Kunde 2;10348;28.01.2019 09:06;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s02;Kunde 2;10333;27.02.2019 20:18;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s03;Kunde 3;10189;18.06.2018 20:07;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s03;Kunde 3;10340;06.02.2019 11:13;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

1. Everything should be sorted by column 2.
2. Columns 1 and 2 should then be deleted
3. The Sold column should be added.(new)
4. Then in column 1 (Sold) the wer s01 should be inserted in each line as long as the customer 1 is in column 2. If customer 2 is in the second column, then the value in the first column should go up from s01 to s02, etc

I'm trying the script right now, unfortunately it doesn't work.

```
sed 's/,/./g' |
awk -F";" 'BEGIN{
 oldRef=""
 OFS="\t"
}{
 if(NR==1){
  $1=$1
 }else{
  if($4 != oldRef){$1="s01";oldRef=$4}else{$1="s02"}
 }
 print $0
}' | column -t -o ";" -s $'\t'
```

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: Your input table seems to be malformed - ending with an unpaired half-quoted field `;"`

Comment: @steeldriver sorry the last character was forgotten when copying, just add it.

Comment: The script in your question that you say you're trying doesn't seem to be in any way related to the problem you're asking for help with. It doesn't sort anything, it's converting `,`s to `.`s for no apparent reason, it's setting OFS to a tab when you don't want your output tab-separated so then you're converting tabs to `;`s, it's testing column 4 when you say in one place you want to sort by column 3 but in another place you say sort by column 2, etc. So when you say "unfortunately it doesn't work" - it's not clear why you ever thought it could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do, using mandatory POSIX tools:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v OFS=';' '{ print (NR>1), $0 }' "${@:--}" |
sort -t';' -k1,1n -k4,4 |
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
    {
        sub(/([^;]*;){3}/,"")
        gsub(/"/,"")
    }
    NR == 1 {
        sold = "Sold"
        $4 = "Column1"
        for ( i=5; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            $i = "_" (i-4)
        }
    }
    NR > 1 {
        if ( $1 != prev ) {
            cnt++
            prev = $1
        }
        sold = sprintf("s%02d",cnt)
    }
    { print sold, $0 }
'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
Sold;CustomerNAME;CustomerID;Date;Column1;_1;_2;_3;_4;_5;_6;_7;_8;_9;_10;_11;_12;_13;_14;_15;_16;_17;_18;_19;_20;_21;_22;_23;_24;_25;_26;_27
s01;Kunde 1;10189;16.05.2018 17:47;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s01;Kunde 1;10229;13.11.2018 11:14;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s01;Kunde 1;10272;20.06.2017 10:35;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s01;Kunde 1;10349;22.02.2019 17:06;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s02;Kunde 2;10207;13.11.2017 14:08;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s02;Kunde 2;10328;09.05.2018 09:22;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s02;Kunde 2;10333;27.02.2019 20:18;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s02;Kunde 2;10348;28.01.2019 09:06;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s03;Kunde 3;10189;18.06.2018 20:07;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s03;Kunde 3;10340;06.02.2019 11:13;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: With the script, the counter is not incremented, everything stays at s01
And from column 6 all column names are overwritten with, _1, _2,_3

Comment: Regarding `the counter is not incremented, everything stays at s01` - I didn't notice in your question that that `s0...` number was changing, I've fixed that now.

Comment: Regarding `from column 6 all column names are overwritten with, _1, _2,_3` - only on the header line as you requested and as you can see in my answer. If you're getting something different then you did something wrong when copy/pasting my script as the loop populating those fields is inside the `NR == 1 { ... }` block that's only executed for the first line of input.

Comment: Or are you saying you actually do NOT want column 6 and on in the output of the header line to be populated with `_1;_2;_3` etc. as you show in the desired output in your question?

Comment: I really don't want the columns to be overwritten

I actually had @Ed Morton on here, but always deletes?

Comment: Then fix the example in your question to show us what you really want. When asking a question it's very important to state+show everything you want and not state+show anything you do not want as all we have to go on when trying to help you solve your problem is what you state+show us in your question.

Comment: Adding a users `@id` to a comment gets deleted if you're commenting under a question or answer posted by that user since they'll automatically be notified of the comment anyway. You only need to `@id` them if posting a comment under someone else's question or answer.

Comment: Ah, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where your `Sold` column comes from, but most of the stuff is pretty basic.

`man cut` will tell you how to cut-off the first two columns. I won't keep you in suspense, it's `cut -'d;' -f3-`.

After that, the customer name is in the first column, so `sort` can be used to sort it in the right order.

You also seems to delete the `"` from the file, so `sed 's/"//g'` would also be needed.

So,

```
cut -'d;' -f3- < table | sed 's/"//g' | sort
```

would do everything but generate the missing column.

Comment: 1. Everything should be sorted by column 2.
2. Columns 1 and 2 should then be deleted
3. The Sold column should be added.(new)
4. Then in column 1 (Sold) the wer s01 should be inserted in each line as long as the customer 1 is in column 2. If customer 2 is in the second column, then the value in the first column should go up from s01 to s02, etc.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of commenting.

Comment: @dima1002 I already added also this to your question, and again it will become visible once accepted. You can do as Cyrus suggests, delete these comments and add them youreslf now.

Answer (score 0):

After removing the unmatched trailing half-field `;"`, then with

```
mlr --icsv --ocsvlite --fs ';' sort -f CustomerNAME then put '
  begin{@s = {}}; 
  @s = mapsum({$CustomerNAME: fmtnum(length(@s)+1,"s%02d")},@s); 
  $Sold = @s[$CustomerNAME]
' then reorder -f Sold then cut -x -f ResNR,ResNAME then rename "",Column_1 input.csv
Sold;CustomerNAME;CustomerID;Date;Column_1;_2;_3;_4;_5;_6;_7;_8;_9;_10;_11;_12;_13;_14;_15;_16;_17;_18;_19;_20;_21;_22;_23;_24;_25;_26;_27
s01;Kunde 1;10272;20.06.2017 10:35;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s01;Kunde 1;10189;16.05.2018 17:47;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s01;Kunde 1;10229;13.11.2018 11:14;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s01;Kunde 1;10349;22.02.2019 17:06;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s02;Kunde 2;10207;13.11.2017 14:08;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s02;Kunde 2;10328;09.05.2018 09:22;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s02;Kunde 2;10348;28.01.2019 09:06;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s02;Kunde 2;10333;27.02.2019 20:18;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s03;Kunde 3;10189;18.06.2018 20:07;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
s03;Kunde 3;10340;06.02.2019 11:13;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

The "trick" here for numbering the `Sold` column is that we attempt to add a new entry to the `@s` out-of-stream map, with key equal to the current CustomerNAME and value one more than the current number of entries in the map; in the case of duplicate keys, the `mapsum` function "prefers" values from the right map.

Comment: In the output header line `Date;;_2;_3` is supposed to be `Date;Column1;_1;_2` per the expected output in the question so there's a missing field and the numbering is off by 1. Not hard to fix afterwards of course but I expect it can probably be output correctly in the first place with a tweak to the script so thought you'd want to know.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks - I've added the easy bit (renaming the empty field name) but for the moment I can't see an easy way to start the disambiguating suffix from _1 instead of _2